# Node.JS -- need help understanding native streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand how the native implementation of streams works. Here's the code:

```js
const Stream = require('stream');

// define a custom class to read my data into the stream
class SourceWrapper extends Stream.Readable {
  constructor(opt, content) {
    super(opt);
    this.content = content;
    this.len = content.length;
    this.index = 0;
  }

  _read() {
    let i = this.index++;
    if (i >= this.len)
      this.push(null);
    else {
      this.push(this.content[i]);
    }
  }
}

// generate some data 
const arr = (new Array(10000000)).fill(1);

// declare the streams
const firstStream = new SourceWrapper({objectMode: true}, arr);

const transform = (x, enc, next) => next(undefined, x * Math.random(x, 10));

const firstMapStream = new Stream.Transform({objectMode: true});
firstMapStream._transform = transform;
const secondMapStream = new Stream.Transform({objectMode: true});
secondMapStream._transform = transform;

// create a promise to measure execution time
const start = new Date();

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  firstStream
  .pipe(firstMapStream)
  .pipe(secondMapStream)
  .on('finish', () => resolve(new Date()));
})
.then((end) => console.log('execTime', end - start));
```

The problem is that it works on small data sets (i.e. `[1,2,3,4]`), but seems to terminate shortly after being run on a large set.

What am I missing? Has it something to do with the `objectMode`?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that someone should to read data from the streams with binding `data` event listener. I've rewrite your code to make it clear to understand the issue. Also i fixed wrong index counting which skipped zero index.

```
'use strict';
const Stream = require('stream');

// define a custom class to read my data into the stream
class SourceWrapper extends Stream.Readable {
  constructor(opt, content) {
    super(opt);
    this.content = content;
    this.len = content.length;
    this.index = 0;
  }

  _read() {
    let i = this.index;
    if (i >= this.len) {
      this.push(null);
    } else {
      this.push(this.content[i]);
    }
    this.index++;
  }
}


const transform = (x, enc, next) => next(undefined, x * Math.random(x, 10));

const transform1 = new Stream.Transform({objectMode: true});
transform1._transform = transform;

const transform2 = new Stream.Transform({objectMode: true});
transform2._transform = transform;


const write = new Stream.Writable({
    objectMode: true,
    write(value, enc, next) {
        // Do something like writing...
        next();
    }
});


// generate some data 
const arr = (new Array(1000000)).fill(1);
const read = new SourceWrapper({objectMode: true}, arr);

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    read
    .pipe(transform1)
    .pipe(transform2)
    .pipe(write)
    .on('finish', () => {
        resolve();
    });
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand now.